# MatBlazor select issue

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

my code should be like this, but it's getting null reference exception

```
 <MatSelect Label="Atık Tipi" @bind-Value="@SecilenAtikGrubu.GrupId" Style="width:100%">
      @foreach (var item in TumAtikTipleri)
     {
        <MatOption Value="@item.Id">@item.Deger1</MatOption>
     }
 </MatSelect>
```

but when i use like this, it is working

```
  <select class="mdc-select__native-control" @bind="SecilenAtikGrubu.GrupId">
     @foreach (var item in TumAtikTipleri)
     {
         <option value="@item.Id">@item.Deger1</option>
     }
  </select>
```

Binding value class is like below (**SecilenAtikGrubu** and **TumAtikTipleri**)

```
 public class GrupKodlari : KayitBilgisi
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Tur { get; set; }
    public string Isim { get; set; }
    public string Deger1 { get; set; }
    public string Deger2 { get; set; }
    public string Deger3 { get; set; }
    public int? GrupId { get; set; } 
    public virtual GrupKodlari Grup { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that none of the `GrupID`s are null? I suspect that MatSelect doesn't handle binding to a null value

Comment: Yes, it works when GrupId is not null, but it should work with null value to.

Comment: Like I said, you don't really know what the `MatSelect` component is doing behind the scenes with the value. It probably doesn't expect a null value. I would suggest opening an issue on their [github](https://github.com/SamProf/MatBlazor/issues)

Comment: thank you, i will.

Comment: Check out MudBlazor. It has a pretty good Select: https://mudblazor.com/components/select

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **bad news** are that, I have checked it and, MatSelect is unable to be binded to a nullable type.

Now the **good news**, first one, you can use an auxiliary property as a workaround, *[Try it at blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/43zc364k).*

```
public int GrupIdAux
{
    set{
        GrupId = (value==0?(int?)null:value);
    }
    get {
        return (GrupId==null?0:GrupId.Value);
    }
}
```

[image: just a sample of the mat select]

Second good new: MatBlazor is an opensource project. If you need to work with nullable types you [can improve MatSelect control](https://github.com/SamProf/MatBlazor/tree/master/src/MatBlazor/Components/MatSelect) and send a PR. The project owner is open to contributions (for example [I wrote NumericUpDown](https://github.com/SamProf/MatBlazor#matblazor-140)) If you can't improve component, you can pay someone to write it for you or you can post a request for the new feature on project issues. It looks like  good idea, would be wonderful to bind nullable objects.

Answer (score 1):

@daniherrera You can bind `MatSelect` to a nullable type. However you have to specify that you accept a nullable type with `?`. Example:

```
<MatSelect Label="Pick a Food Group" @bind-Value="@guidValue">
    <MatOption TValue="Guid?" Value="@(null)"></MatOption>
    <MatOption TValue="Guid?" Value="@(new Guid("20A82054-F493-4C7B-81A4-4F9A1EDD7C2E"))">Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta</MatOption>
    <MatOption TValue="Guid?" Value="@(new Guid("4451642D-24F7-418F-8741-BA5089A1CC65"))">Vegetables</MatOption>
    <MatOption TValue="Guid?" Value="@(new Guid("5717DBBE-C205-4E33-9E07-892A51F64021"))">Fruit</MatOption>
</MatSelect>

<span>@guidValue</span>

@code
{
    Guid? guidValue = new Guid("20A82054-F493-4C7B-81A4-4F9A1EDD7C2E");
}
```

https://www.matblazor.com/Select#MatSelectGuid

Use `int? Id` and mark your `MatOption` with `TValue="int?"`.

Answer (score 0):

My way to solve it is:

```
<MudSelect T="Genre?" Label="Genre Primary" @bind-Value="model.MainGenrePrimary" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
<MudSelectItem T="Genre?"></MudSelectItem>
@foreach (Genre item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Genre)))
{
   <MudSelectItem T="Genre?" Value="@item">@item</MudSelectItem>
}
</MudSelect>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).